# Converting a non-linear HTML based CD-Rom into an ebook

Tags: ebooks

I have a CD-rom that is the "director's cut" of a comic. It contains every page in penciled format; then also each page in inks and then also in colour and finally annotations.

My problem is this: the CD is not linear. You can go from, say, page 3 pencils to page 3 inks to page 3 colours to page 45 pencils. All ebook authoring (and viewing) software seems to only support strictly linear viewing; not the "matrix" style I have on the CD.

[image]

My question is: is there any way to make this into an ebook?  I am not looking for an automated conversion tool, I am more than happy to redo every page. I just need to know that the "vertical" scrolling is supported as well as the traditional "horizontal" scrolling.

Comment: I suspect the correct term may be hypertext novel, and there's nearly nothing I can think of, short of html that may do this.  You might want to copy some of the further descriptions of what you need off your website so people understand what you need better

I *do* know ebooks handle links of sorts, but the software for building the ebook might end up being simple (like calibre) or complex). You could alternately just do what I did with the baen free library and covert the cd into a zipped folder of folders.

Comment: Most ebook formats support linking within the text, so at a minimum, you could put several links on each page. That wouldn't look great though.

It looks like the ePUB spec supports HTML image maps (discussion [here][http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=85790], epub spec [here][2]). Using image maps would allow you to make 'links' on the images and therefore the user could tap say the bottom of each pencil to go to the corresponding ink.

Comment: What is your audience? Must be the resulting format inevitably an ebook? (ePUB etc.)